# Error 310: Staging failed: 'Staging task failed: - CloudFoundry

Tags: playframework, cloud-foundry

Getting an Error 310 when trying to stage my Play Framework java sample.  Any assistance would be much appreciated:

Full error output here:

https://t.co/F0Zh2bY4

Comment: Can you share your app source as well so I can try to repro the issue on Cloud Foundry?

Comment: Absolutely.  I am uploading the file to the same Dropbox directory as above. Should be done uploading in a bit.  I have zipped it up in a file called SecureSocial.zip Thanks Glenn!

Answer (score 3):

Cloud Foundry requires Play apps to be pushed as zip files built with the `play dist` command: http://blog.cloudfoundry.com/2012/05/31/cloud-foundry-now-supports-play/

I was able to push your app on Mac OS X with the following:

```
~/Downloads/SecureSocial $ sbt play clean dist
~/Downloads/SecureSocial $ vmc push --path modules/securesocial/dist/securesocial-AuthDemo.zip
```

Comment: OK.  so now Im using the "play clean dist" instead of "play dist" and that's cool.  The vmc push command returns "Unknown symbol in manifest: name".  It probably doesn't like the some syntax in the manifest.  How are you getting it to push with this command.  In the past I have manually edited the manifest.yml file but its not creating one in this instance for me to modify?

Comment: Well,  I pushed the app up to cloudfoundry using all the command line switches.  "vmc update AuthDemo --path dist/AuthDemo.zip --url AuthDemo.cloudfoundry.com --instances 1  --mem 256 --no-start"  and everything pushed and started fine.  Wouldn't work for me with just vmc push --path modules/securesocial/dist/AuthDemo.zip.  Go figure.  Consider this closed.  Thanks and Cheers!