# Cloud Foundry Playframework : Error 310: Staging failed:

Tags: playframework-2.0, cloud-foundry

I am trying to host a sample (HelloWorld) Play app in Cloud Foundry but am always getting this error at Staging,

```
Error 310: Staging failed: 'Staging task failed:
 Staging plugin failed: cp: cannot stat `/var/vcap/data/stager/tmp/d20120828-24156-128z05h/unstaged/logs/*': No such file or directory
/var/vcap/data/packages/ruby/6.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1231:in `chmod': No such file or directory - /var/vcap/data/stager/tmp/d20120828-24156-128z05h/staged/app/start (Errno::ENOENT)
    from /var/vcap/data/packages/ruby/6.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1231:in `chmod'
    from /var/vcap/data/packages/ruby/6.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:879:in `block in chmod'
    from /var/vcap/data/packages/ruby/6.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:878:in `each'
    from /var/vcap/data/packages/ruby/6.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:878:in `chmod'
    from /var/vcap/packages/stager/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/vcap_staging-0.1.62/lib/vcap/staging/plugin/play/plugin.rb:14:in `block in stage_application'
    from /var/vcap/packages/stager/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/vcap_staging-0.1.62/lib/vcap/staging/plugin/play/plugin.rb:11:in `chdir'
    from /var/vcap/packages/stager/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/vcap_staging-0.1.62/lib/vcap/staging/plugin/play/plugin.rb:11:in `stage_application'
    from /var/vcap/packages/stager/bin/run_plugin:19:in `<main>'
```

I am quite new to this so have no idea on what it means. I also tried googling but to no avail.

I tried this one too but it didn't work [SO Question similar to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11658029/error-310-staging-failed-staging-task-failed-cloudfoundry)

---

**EDIT:**
*The above link pointed works, just make sure you provide the app name in vmc push command
 as denoted by answer.*

---

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks.

***Dev Environment:***

- Play 2.0 - Scala based
- Ubuntu 12.04
- vmc to deploy the app.

**Additional info:**

I followed this tutorial [Play scala Cloud Foundry](http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/frameworks/play/scala-getting-started.html)

```
Would you like to deploy from the current directory? [Yn]: 
Application Name: HelloSample
Detected a Standalone Application, is this correct? [Yn]: n
1: Play
2: Lift
3: JavaWeb
4: Node
5: Standalone
6: Rails
7: Spring
8: Rack
9: Grails
10: Sinatra
Select Application Type: 1
Selected Play Framework Application
Application Deployed URL [HelloSample.cloudfoundry.com]: hellosample.cloudfoundry.com
Memory reservation (128M, 256M, 512M, 1G, 2G) [256M]: 
How many instances? [1]: 
1
Create services to bind to 'HelloSample'? [yN]: 1
Would you like to save this configuration? [yN]: y
Manifest written to manifest.yml.
Creating Application: OK
Uploading Application:
  Checking for available resources: OK
  Processing resources: OK
  Packing application: OK
  Uploading (106K): OK   
Push Status: OK
Staging Application 'HelloSample': ..Error 310: Staging failed: 'Staging task failed:
 Staging plugin failed: cp: cannot stat `/var/vcap/data/stager/tmp/d20120828-24156-128z05h/unstaged/logs/*': No such file or directory
/var/vcap/data/packages/ruby/6.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1231:in `chmod': No such file or directory - /var/vcap/data/stager/tmp/d20120828-24156-128z05h/staged/app/start (Errno::ENOENT)
    from /var/vcap/data/packages/ruby/6.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1231:in `chmod'
    from /var/vcap/data/packages/ruby/6.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:879:in `block in chmod'
    from /var/vcap/data/packages/ruby/6.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:878:in `each'
    from /var/vcap/data/packages/ruby/6.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:878:in `chmod'
    from /var/vcap/packages/stager/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/vcap_staging-0.1.62/lib/vcap/staging/plugin/play/plugin.rb:14:in `block in stage_application'
    from /var/vcap/packages/stager/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/vcap_staging-0.1.62/lib/vcap/staging/plugin/play/plugin.rb:11:in `chdir'
    from /var/vcap/packages/stager/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/vcap_staging-0.1.62/lib/vcap/staging/plugin/play/plugin.rb:11:in `stage_application'
    from /var/vcap/packages/stager/bin/run_plugin:19:in `<main>'
'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to run the "dist" command in Play. This produces a zip file in the ./dist folder, you can the push the app with the 'path' switch like so;

```
vmc push <app-name-goes-here> --path=dist/<generated-zip-file>.zip
```

VMC should recognise this as a Play application and deploy it correctly.