# Unable to update Play! Scala app to CloudFoundry

Tags: scala, playframework, cloud-foundry, vmc

Im having the same problem as this user:
[Cloud Foundry Playframework : Error 310: Staging failed:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12161698/cloud-foundry-playframework-error-310-staging-failed)

I added a mysql service to my app. I updated the app with the command:

```
vmc update app-name --path=dist/my-dist.zip
```

It responds saying the update is ok. When I go to my apps view, it says the app is stopped. When i try executing

```
vmc start app-name
```

it crashes with the same error:

```
vmc start app-name
Staging Application 'app-name': ...Error 310: Staging failed: 'Staging task failed:
Staging plugin failed: /var/vcap/data/packages/ruby/6.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1231:in `chmod': No such file or directory - /var/vcap/data/stager/tmp/d20120924-9953-1jfgi5c/staged/app/start (Errno::ENOENT)
from /var/vcap/data/packages/ruby/6.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1231:in `chmod'
from /var/vcap/data/packages/ruby/6.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:879:in `block in chmod'
from /var/vcap/data/packages/ruby/6.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:878:in `each'
from /var/vcap/data/packages/ruby/6.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:878:in `chmod'
from /var/vcap/packages/stager/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/vcap_staging-0.1.63/lib/vcap/staging/plugin/play/plugin.rb:10:in `block in stage_application'
from /var/vcap/packages/stager/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/vcap_staging-0.1.63/lib/vcap/staging/plugin/play/plugin.rb:7:in `chdir'
from /var/vcap/packages/stager/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/vcap_staging-0.1.63/lib/vcap/staging/plugin/play/plugin.rb:7:in `stage_application'
from /var/vcap/packages/stager/bin/run_plugin:19:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update on the previous post (addressing scala specifically):**

1. please avoid using a manifest at this time
2. vmc push
3. after you do an app change:

`play clean dist && vmc update <app> --path <app dist path>`

Here is my example:

```
play clean dist && vmc update ghelloworld --path "/Users/ggross/Dropbox/play-work/helloworld-scala/dist"
```

**Original answer (addresses java deployment):**

Ok, I don't have your app specifically, so here is what I did. Using the example at [Start Cloudfoundry](http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/frameworks/play/java-getting-started.html)

I created the example Play! app, and deployed to Cloudfoundry. I was careful to select "2 - Create a simple Java application".

I then made a simple change to "Application.java".

Next I did the following:

```
$vmc dist
$vmc update garyhelloplay --path=dist/garyhello-java-1.0-SNAPSHOT.zip
```

This completed successfully, and I was able to view the result from my browser.
NOTE: the first deployment took a *long* time (minutes), so that required some patience. If you would like us to review your app specifically, please open a ticket at [Cloudfoundry Support](http://support.cloudfoundry.com), we will take a look, and post the results here.

Comment: Hi eightyoctane, thanks for your help. Could you please confirm that what you did also works for a Scala app. It seems to me that you did it for a Java app, and considering that you also have a tutorial for Scala Im not sure if you want me to try this for Scala also. Ill try it anyways and if doesnt work, Ill open the ticket :). Thanks for your help!

Comment: Got it. Working on this through the ticketing system and will post updates here.

Comment: Thanks a lot eightoctane! It works great now, all I needed to do was delete the Manifest.yml.